How can I calculate the highly oscillatory integral $\int _{-1}^1\exp({x+\sin(\exp(\exp(\exp({x+1/3)))})})\,\mathrm{d}x$ numerically?
Code for the integral:
NIntegrate[Exp[x + Sin[Exp@Exp@Exp[x + 1/3]]], {x, -1, 1}]

It returns warnings and cannot give a precise result. I tried to specify the Method but I cannot find any one that helps.

Are we allowed to manipulate the expression?

If we change Variables: Exp[-1/3] NIntegrate[Exp[Sin[x]]/(   x Log[x]), {x, Exp[Exp[Exp[-2/3]]], Exp[Exp[Exp[4/3]]]},    Method -> "LocalAdaptive"] gives: $2.33365$.

@MariuszIwaniuk did it give you some error message about failed to converge? I had the same value but the error was "large"

@Confuse-ray30 On version MMA: 13.3,14.0,14.1 No error message, with my code on the comment.

Alright. Guess I just never tried localadaptive

@MariuszIwaniuk It works. But when I add option WorkingPrecision, it returns a lot of warning, like Exp[-1/3] NIntegrate[Exp[Sin[x]]/(x Log[x]), {x, Exp[Exp[Exp[-2/3]]], Exp[Exp[Exp[4/3]]]}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive", WorkingPrecision -> 50]

@MariuszIwaniuk Exp[-1/3] NIntegrate[Exp[Sin[x]]/(x Log[x]), {x, Exp[Exp[Exp[-2/3]]], 1000, 1000000, 1000000000, 1000000000000, Exp[Exp[Exp[4/3]]]}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive", MaxRecursion -> 20] yields 3.00398 with no messages. I wouldn't be surprised if this integral cannot be done (to more than a few digits).

I recognized this integral as one that was posted as a problem extending those presented in "The SIAM 100-Digit Challenge" (there's an excellent book presenting detailed solutions to the 10 original problems, and giving the additional ones) a few years ago. I solved it, and did a (too long) writeup, linked to here:
Solution to SIAM Problem 7
The goal in these problems was to obtain answers to very many digits.
EDIT:
Here's brief summary of the approach I used in the linked document. I used the same change of variables as Mariusz, and expanded the term $\exp(\sin x)$ in a Taylor series, obtaining
$$
I = c   \int_a^b dx \frac{1}{x \log x} \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{\sin^n x}{n!} , 
$$
where $c= \exp(-1/3), a = \exp(\exp(\exp(-2/3)))$, and $b = \exp(\exp(\exp(4/3))).$ Then write $\sin(x) = \frac{e^{i x} - e^{-i x}}{2 i}$ and use the binomial theorem to get
$$
I_N = c\int_a^b d x \frac{1}{x \log x} \sum_{n=0}^N \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{e^{i x(n-2k)}}{(2 i)^n} \frac{(-1)^k}{n!} \binom{n}{k}
$$ where we limited the infinite sum to a maximum of $N$, and the integral will be given by the limit $N\rightarrow \infty$.
Switching the order of sums and integral we get
$$
I_N = c \sum_{n=0}^{N} \sum_{k=0}^{n}  
\frac{1}{(2 i)^n} \frac{(-1)^k}{n!} \binom{n}{k}
R_{n-2k} ,
$$
where
$$
R_{m} = \int_a^b dx \frac{e^{i m x}}{x \log x}.
$$
I used a contour into the upper half of the complex plane to make the integral $R_m$ converge better, and calculated it with the double-exponential option of NIntegrate[]. Here is the (not well-written)) code, designed to show how the number of correct digits increases with $N$:
a = Exp[Exp[Exp[-2/3]]];

b = Exp[Exp[Exp[4/3]]];

c = Exp[-1/3];

fval500 = 
  Table[NIntegrate[1/(z*Log[z]) Exp[I k z], {z, a, a + 500*I}, 
      PrecisionGoal -> 80, WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
      Method -> DoubleExponential] + 
      NIntegrate[1/(z*Log[z]) Exp[I k z], {z, b + 500*I, b}, 
      PrecisionGoal -> 80, WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
      Method -> DoubleExponential], {k, 1, 81, 1}];


 fv[k_] := If[k > 0, fval500[[k]], Conjugate[fval500[[-k]]]];

 fv[0] = Log[Log[b]] - Log[Log[a]];

 WorkingPrecision -> 100;

 For[NN = 3, NN <= 80, NN++,
     For[sum = 0; n = 0, n <= NN, n++, 
        For[k = 0, k <= n, k++, 
            sum = sum + 1/n! (-1)^k 1/(2 I)^n 
                  Binomial[n, k] fv[n - 2*k]
        ]
     ];
     val[NN] = c*sum
 ]

I made a table of results using
Table[{j, Chop[val[j]]}, {j, 3, 72}] // TableForm

It is too large to show here. For example, for N=20,30, and 70 I get (truncating a lot of the digits):
2.99633981197653537918222375683707383853672096918515035553078866
2.99633981197653537918286155623550188492945079268408699783359488
2.99633981197653537918286155623550188766809645625482915948160883
The result for N=70 is correct to 100 digits. See the pdf for full results.
Regards,
Tom

Answers should generally be self-contained. Can you please edit the answer and include the relevant Mathematica code with a brief summary of what is goinf on, and leave the reference link for further reading?

Will do, thanks for the comment.
